# Is there any way to filter or ignore messages written to log?

Tags: postgresql

My database is behind a load balancer and even though the health check interval is set to 10secs, im getting multiple checks per second which result in thousands of "incomplete startup packet" messages written to the logfile.

This makes it hard to find errors when I have to scroll forever in the log file to find actual errors.

Is there any way to ignore just the message "incomplete startup packet" from being written to the log?

Answer (score 1):

In **postgresql.conf** the parameter `log_checkpoints` (boolean) causes checkpoints and restartpoints to be logged in the server log. Some statistics are included in the log messages, including the number of buffers written and the time spent writing them. This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command line. The default is off.

Not sure if this is the same thing, is yours commented or not?

```
#log_checkpoints = off
```

And anyway if you viewed your log using something like Glogg you could set an exclude pattern like:

```
^(?!.*incomplete startup packet).*$
```

As simple as that.

Comment: I have `log_checkpoints=off` in my config by default, but I'm still getting this annoying `LOG:  incomplete startup packet` message every time a monitoring agent makes a TCP connection to :5432.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, unless you are willing to make a minor source-code change and compile your own PostgreSQL.

It would probably be more productive to try to solve at a higher or lower level, either fixing the bug in the load balancer, or adopting a log-miner that makes it easier to filter things like that out.